# Warning out of range value column for conditional update

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a single query to update a table and some fields should be updated under conditions, lets imagine this case:

I have a table called *mytable*, it has a `DATETIME` field called *installed*, this field can be null and is null by default, and sometimes some values are '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

When I get data from any sensor (example: sensor id 12457) I update its values like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET
temperature=35,
pressure=122,
installed=NOW(),
status=1
WHERE id=12457
```

if I get a new data from the same sensor I store its values again but I avoid changing the installed value this way:

```
UPDATE mytable SET
temperature=35,
pressure=122,
installed=IF(installed IS NULL,NOW(),installed),
status=1
WHERE id=12457
```

It works as expected, if installed is null it store the current time, if isn't it keeps the previous date, but I get this warning when date is '0000-00-00 00:00:00':

Warning: Out of range value for column 'installed' at row 1

As **D-Shih** suggested, I tried using COALESCE as the following, but I got the same warning:

```
installed=COALESCE(installed,NOW())
```

I thought it is because the previous date, so, I tried to reproduce the error intentionally doing this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET
installed=installed,
WHERE id=12457
```

But I didn't get any warning.

System works correctly, but I am a little curious, Why I get this warning using an IF (or COALESCE) function only?

---

*Answering **Madhur Bhaiya**:*

`SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable`

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `temperature` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `pressure` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `installed` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (12457, 35, 122, '2018-12-12 12:53:49', 1);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (12458, 40, 119, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 1);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (12459, 34, 122, null, 1);
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (12460, 36, 122, '2018-12-12 12:57:01', 1);
```

MySQL version: 5.7.23

Comment: share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` result. Also, share the details of some sample data. Also, what is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: P.Salmon now you say this, I have this warning on dates like `0000-00-00 00:00:00` only, It could be the cause?

Comment: Why do you have `0000-00-00` date values ?

Comment: I don't really know, sensors are made with Raspberry PI reading a CSV string, I think they sometimes are not able to read the date correctly.

Comment: Try `COALESCE(CAST(installed AS DATETIME), CAST(NOW() AS DATETIME))`. Just out of curiosity...

Comment: Alexey, nice, no warning using CAST in installed: `installed=COALESCE(CAST(installed AS DATETIME), NOW())`, why I have to CAST it if this is already DATETIME? and why I have no warning doing this: `installed=installed`?

Comment: @stramin, I think this is because NOW() returns a string, while the value of `installed` field is of type DATETIME. And for some reason, mysql doesn't like that in the same IF or COALESCE you have values of two different types.

Comment: Hmm... no, my previous comment is not correct. You are not casting `NOW()` and anyway not getting the warning.

Comment: Is it maybe a MySQL bug or something? :o

Answer (score 1):

You have `0000-00-00 00:00:00` as values also in `installed` column. You need to handle them as well, besides the `null` values. Also before running the query, you need to set `sql_mode` to `''`, as it will remove the stricter [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) SQL mode.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';

UPDATE mytable 
SET
  temperature = 35,
  pressure = 122,
  installed = IF(installed IS NULL OR installed = '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                 NOW(),
                 installed),
  status=1
WHERE id=12457
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I get a new warning: `Warning: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'installed' at row 1`, now I am even more curious about this... And I still wondering why this happens on conditional functions only?